# Mocking method IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

**I want to mock this interface using Moq:**

```
IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
```

**Below are the code calling in a method that wants to mock**

```
string notificationMedium = await _notificationTypeRepository
.FindBy(x => x.Alias.ToLower().Equals(request.NotificationType.ToLower())).Select(x => x.NotificationMedium).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

**I was thinking of doing something like**

```
repository.Setup(x => x.FindBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<NotificationType, bool>>>()))
                .Returns((Func<Expression<Func<NotificationType, bool>>, IQueryable<NotificationType>>)(expression => list.AsQueryable().Where(expression)));
```

**When I try to debug the unit test where I need this mocking, it says that**

```
ValidateCreateNotificationCommandHandler
   Duration: 8.3 sec

  Message: 
    TestBase.Assertion`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]] : Failed : 
    Should not contain x => x.Matches("Error", RegexOptions.None)
    Actual : 
    ----------------------------
    
    ----------------------------
    Asserted : actual => !a.Any(predicate.Compile())
              predicate   →   x => x.Matches("Error", RegexOptions.None)
    predicate.Compile()   →   System.Func`2[System.String,System.Boolean]
    

  Stack Trace: 
    Assert.That[T](T actual, Expression`1 predicate, String comment, Object[] commentArgs)
    IEnumerableShoulds.ShouldNotContain[T](IEnumerable`1 actual, Expression`1 predicate, String comment, Object[] args)
    CreateNotificationCommandHandlersTester.ValidateCreateNotificationCommandHandler() line 84
    GenericAdapter`1.GetResult()
    AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
    TestMethodCommand.RunTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
    TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
    <>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Execute>b__0()
    BeforeAndAfterTestCommand.RunTestMethodInThreadAbortSafeZone(TestExecutionContext context, Action action)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add Namespace MockQueryable-**

```
using MockQueryable.Moq;
```

**Change code -**

```
Mock<IQueryable<NotificationType>> mock = list.AsQueryable().BuildMock();
repository.Setup(x => x.FindBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<NotificationType, bool>>>())).Returns(mock.Object);
```

Code will work!